# Obj-C - Sorting tableview data by date(s) in string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, uitableview

I have an array (self.filteredArray) that returns dictionaries in which the key scheduleddate contains today's date (in this case, Apr 12 2021). Console returns the following:

```
2021-04-12 09:14:30.942723-0700 [58012:24654705] The filtered please (
            {
    
            "node_title" = "Elisa Carmichael";
            scheduleddate = "Apr 12 2021 1:00 PM";
        
        },
            {
           
            "node_title" = "Michael Levy";
            scheduleddate = "Apr 10 2021 11:00 AM, Apr 12 2021 5:00 PM";

        },
            {
            
            "node_title" = "Trisha Johnson";
            scheduleddate = "Apr 12 2021 6:00 PM";

        }
    )
```

My goal is to arrange these individuals in a "Today" tableview in order of the time that they're scheduled. The below code works perfectly when scheduleddate only contains ONE date and time, ie. Apr 12 2021 1:00 PM. However some individuals are scheduled for multiple dates and times in the same scheduleddate string (in the above, Michael Levy), and this breaks the sorting order.

Is there a way for me to write the below code so that the final array (self.sortedByTime) arranges the returned individuals ONLY by the value separated by "," that contains today's date?

I hope this makes sense. THANK YOU.

**ViewController.m**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
        if (tableView == self.todaytableView) {
    
    self.sortedByTime = [self.filteredArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2)


                {
              
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < [self.filteredArray count]; i++) {
    
      }
                  
                    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1[@"scheduleddate"]];
                    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2[@"scheduleddate"]];
                    return [date1 compare:date2];
                }];
              
    
                 self.finalTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.sortedByTime];
    
           
                
            return [self.finalTimes count];
                
            }
```

**My target output:**

```
2021-04-12 09:14:30.942723-0700 [58012:24654705] The filtered please (
            {
    
            "node_title" = "Elisa Carmichael";
            scheduleddate = "Apr 12 2021 1:00 PM";
        
        },
            {
           
            "node_title" = "Michael Levy";
            scheduleddate = "Apr 12 2021 5:00 PM";

        },
            {
            
            "node_title" = "Trisha Johnson";
            scheduleddate = "Apr 12 2021 6:00 PM";

        }
    )
```

Comment: Didn't we suggest you already to use Models, not `NSDictionary`? ie, custom `NSObject` with a property `NSString` named `title`, a `NSDate` property (or an NSArray if needed, if you can have multiple as that's the case), and if you have two dates, what's the logic? You want to duplicate the NSDictionary? Use the latest date to compare? The ealier one? The most "close" to Today ?

Comment: There's a reason I'm not using NSObject. I simply want my above code to arrange today's times in my tableView from earliest to latest. I just can't seem to access "today's time" if multiple dates are listed in the obj1[scheduleddate] or obj2[scheduleddate] strings. @Larme

Comment: You want to sort or filter. It's unclear. What's the target output? and if you have also `{ "node_title" = "Michael Levy with old date"; scheduleddate = "Apr 01 2021 11:00 AM, Apr 03 2021 5:00 PM";}` should it appear? Where? And you shouldn't sort in `numberOfRowsInSection:`, you'll call that method too many times, it should be sorted only once.

Comment: Ahh @Larme see my target nsdictionary output above! Added it to the question. I essentially just want to remove any string within my string that doesn't contain 'Apr 12 2021'. Apologies for the wordy explanation lol. And agree, just realizing I should move this outside of numberOfRowsInSection! Your help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not about sorting. It's about filtering and mapping.

Why?
You need to filter because you want to reject some values.
You need to "map" because you want to change some values.

So we do a manual filter since we want to map at the same time, ie: a simple for loop, and for each element, we check if within the dates strings, there is a "today" date candidate, and we keep the first one found.

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"node_title": @"Elisa Carmichael",
                      @"scheduleddate": @"Apr 12 2021 1:00 PM"},
                   @{@"node_title": @"Michael Levy",
                      @"scheduleddate": @"Apr 10 2021 11:00 AM, Apr 12 2021 5:00 PM"},
                   @{@"node_title": @"Trisha Johnson",
                     @"scheduleddate":@"Apr 12 2021 6:00 PM"}];

NSMutableArray *mappedAndfiltered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *aDict in array) {
    NSString *scheduledDatesString = aDict[@"scheduleddate"];
    NSArray *dates = [scheduledDatesString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSUInteger candidateIndex = [dates indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString * _Nonnull dateStr, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        return [dateStr containsString:@"Apr 12 2021"]; //That's for the tests, but in fact, use your NSDateFormatter and check if the NSDate is today, I was just lazy to redo a formatter for your sample and check if it's within today
    }];
    if (candidateIndex != NSNotFound) {
        [mappedAndfiltered addObject:@{@"node_title": aDict[@"node_title"],
                                       @"scheduleddate": dates[candidateIndex]}];
    }
}

NSLog(@"mappedAndfiltered: %@", mappedAndfiltered);
```

//Now, sort again using your current method

**BUT**:

I strongly advice to use custom `NSObject`, a model.
Because you keep manipulating NSString, where they should be `NSDate` and you keep on doing conversion between them to sort, edit your data, etc. The string representation should be kept for the user only, not the developer. Else, it's prone to errors.

With a quick model:

```
@interface MyModel: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dates;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *dateWithinToday;

-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict;
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title dateStrings:(NSArray *)commaSeparatedDateStrings;
@end
@implementation MyModel

-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {

    if (self == [self initWithTitle:dict[@"node_title"] dateStrings:[dict[@"scheduleddate"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]]) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title dateStrings:(NSArray *)commaSeparatedDateStrings {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        _title = title;
        NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSString *aDateStr in commaSeparatedDateStrings) {
            //Use a "single formatter"
            [datesArray addObject:[__dateFormatter dateFromString:aDateStr]];
        }
        _dates = datesArray;
        NSUInteger index = [datesArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDate * _Nonnull date, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:date];
        }];
        if (index != NSNotFound) {
            _dateWithinToday = datesArray[index];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - title: %@ - todaydate: %@ - all dates: %@" , [super description], _title, _dateWithinToday, _dates];
}
@end
```

And in use:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *aDict in array) {
    [arrayOfObjects addObject:[[MyModel alloc] initWithDict:aDict]];
}

NSPredicate *todayPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(MyModel * _Nullable aModel, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    return [aModel dateWithinToday] != nil;
}];
NSArray *filtered = [arrayOfObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:todayPredicate];
NSArray *sorted = [filtered sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MyModel * _Nonnull obj1, MyModel * _Nonnull obj2) {
    return [[obj1 dateWithinToday] compare:[obj2 dateWithinToday]];
}];

NSLog(@"sorted: %@", sorted);
```

Comment: You are a god. LOL. Thank you SO much. I'll attempt to heed your advice and go the NSObject route.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you want to sort your array of dictionaries by the Date value in the `scheduleddate` key.

If `scheduleddate` sometimes contains multiple dates, it would be simpler if you could assume the correct date is the last one. Failing that, do this:

write a function `dateTodayFromString(_:)` that takes a String and returns a Date.

Have it use the `NSString` method `containsString` to determine if it contains a comma. If it doesn't, just apply the date formatter and return the resulting Date.

If it does, use `componentsSeparatedByString: ", "` to break the multiple dates apart. Convert each one into a `Date` using your `DateFormatter`, loop through the array of Dates and use the `Calendar` function `isDateInToday` to find a date that is in the current day. If it finds one, return that.

Rewrite your sort function to call your `dateTodayFromString(_:)` function to get a date from the string in each array entry.

Note that if your array contains more than ≈100 entries you should really convert the array to an array of mutable dictionaries and go through a pass converting all those date strings to Date objects before you try to sort it. converting date strings to dates for every comparison makes the sorting process a lot slower (I seem to remember that it took like 12 times longer on a modest sized array when I tested it, but I'd have to go back and test it.)